# AWS Cognito Sign In, No response

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I did not want to use the AWSCognito UI, hence I found some work on GitHub regarding SignIn independent of the UI. However, when I implement it, there is no response and nothing happens.

Code:

```
if (!((self.emailTextField.text?.isEmpty)!) && !(self.passwordTextField.text?.isEmpty)!)
    {
        print("in")
        let authDetails = AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationDetails(username: self.emailTextField.text!, password: self.passwordTextField.text! )
        self.passwordAuthenticationCompletion?.set(result: authDetails)
        let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") 
        self.present(next!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("out")
    }
```

Comment: You have to use the AWS Js SDK to implement this. check this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html)

Comment: But I am developing an iOS app, not JS

Comment: Sorry for that. Refer this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-ios-sdk.html)

Comment: I referred that link and the code I posted is a part of it.